# Disabling The Start Screen Of MS Office 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

MS Office 2013 introduced a start screen feature along similar lines to that of Windows 8.  The left hand pane lists the most recently opened documents, whilst the right hand pane displays different formats and templates of the document which are available for creating a new document (of Word 2013).

However I am more comfortable with the old layout, and wish to know how to disable this start screen (either via registry hack or otherwise) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click *File*, then *Options*.
2. In the *General* window, look into the "*Start up options*" section.
3. Uncheck the box labelled "Show the Start screen when this application starts*.
4. Click *OK*.

Additional info here: [How to Bypass or Disable the Office 2013 Start Screen](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-bypass-or-disable-the-office-2013-start-screen/)

Comment: The article appears very good. With regards to the methodology described above, i'm guessing that would have to be carried out for each of the Office Apps concerned ?

Comment: Yes, this method will need to be done in each app in Office.  The link provided also includes a registry editing method that will apply to all installed Office applications.