# How to disable Office 2016 start screen?

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

[Here's the Question for 2013](https://superuser.com/q/652906/116196)

It seems it's different in 2016 than 2013. Where can I find this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the **gallery** in office 2016, but it's called a different gallery for different applications.

Go to file - preferences - general and uncheck the option *open the ___ gallery when opening Application*

Excel - workbook gallery

[image]

Word - document gallery

[image]